# GWT Cell Table Clicking on a new row gives value of Previously selected row

Tags: gwt

In GWT 2.6 CellTable, I'm writing a single click event to perform some operation. I can not get the correct Row Index while clicking on the CellTable Row; only a double click event returns the row correctly.

```
final SingleSelectionModel<PatientDTO> selectionModel = 
    new SingleSelectionModel<PatientDTO>();

patientsTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);  

patientsTable.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler()  
{  
    @Override  
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)  
    {
        PatientDTO selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
        if (selected != null) 
        {
            RootLayoutPanel.get().clear();
            RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new PatientPanel(selected));
        }
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `SingleSelectionModel` or `MultiSelectionModel` and add `SelectionChangeHandler` on it that will be fired when selection is changed in the `CellTable`

Sample code:

```
final SingleSelectionModel<Contact> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Contact>();
//final MultiSelectionModel<Contact> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<Contact>();
selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {

    @Override
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
        Set<Contact> selected = selectionModel.getSelectedSet();
        if (selected != null) {
            for (Contact contact : selected) {
                System.out.println("You selected: " + contact.name);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

OR alternatively try with `CellPreviewHandler`

```
table.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<Contact>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Contact> event) {
        int row = event.getIndex();
        int column = event.getColumn();

        if ("focus".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
           //..
        }
        if ("blur".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            //...
        }
        if ("mousedown".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            //..
        }
        if ("mouseover".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            //..
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I used SingleSelectionModel and now it opens the newly clicked row,but it does not first selects(I want to select by first click  and than on single click on the same row perform the operation otherwise click on other row selects the other row).